# How do I calculate the binary form of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, binary

The 4 bytes used in CDROM sectors is just a usual 32 bit CRC.  It uses the polynomial

```
P(x) = (x^16 + x^15 + x^2 + 1).(x^16 + x^2 + x + 1)
```

which expands to

```
x^32 + x^31 + 2x^18 + 2x^17 + 3x^16 + x^15 + x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1
```

The CRC process reverses the bits of the input bytes and the final CRC value.  It is stored in big endian format in the sector.

So I have to pass a polynomial prime into crc32 algorithm.

How do I convert this polynomial expression into binary form. any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: The coefficients of those polynomials are surely elements of the binary field. So $2x^{18}=0x^{18}=0$ et cetera.

Comment: As to the rest, I think that the technical specs should describe that in detail. Anyway, you form a high degree polynomial by reading individual bits of the bytes on the disk in the prescribed order. Including the 32-bit check sequence. Then the CRC-check is to test the resulting polynomial (of degree up to a bit less than $2^{16}=65536$) is divisible by the check polynomial. Some protocols require you to invert a part of the bits - see the specs if this applies to CDROM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a CRC32 algorithm with the polynomial
$$x^{32} + x^{31} + 2x^{18} + 2x^{17} + 3x^{16} + x^{15} + x^4 + x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1$$
you first omit the $x^{32}$ term and reduce the remaining coefficients mod 2. This gives
$$x^{31} + x^{16} + x^{15} + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$$
Now simply substitute $x=2\;$ and evaluate, this gives the 32 bit number for
the CRC polynomial:

$$10000000000000011000000000011011_2 = 8001801B_{16} = 2147581979_{10}
$$

But note that for an actual implementation there more design subtleties: Are
you using big-endian or little endian? There are different reflections modes,
initial values, final xoring etc.

Comment: The least significant bit of a data byte is used first. 
The least significant parity bit (x 0 ) is stored in the most significant bit position when storing polynomial

Comment: The conversion is done by the compiler or interpreter if you enter the number 
`0x8001801B` or  `2147581979`. But you need more to actually implement the algorithm, see Ross Williams text e.g. http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt or (as HTML) http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/crc_v3.html.

Comment: "and reduce the remaining coefficients mod 2" What do you mean? mod 2 = modulo 2 I assume but i don't see anything being modulod or how that would result from modulo?

Comment: What does this "reduce the remaining coefficients mod 2" mean?

Do you replace the X with a 1 or something, and the find what 1 to the power of 31 is?

and how do you represent which polynomials aren't "on" when 0 to the power of X is 0, just like x^28 is 0?

Comment: @MarcusJ: It has the obvious meaning, i.e. if the polynomial is $\sum a_i x^i$ compute $a_i\pmod 2$. In the example the part $2x^{18} + 2x^{17} + 3x^{16} +\dots + 2x^2$ will become $x^{16}$ because the other coefficients are zero mod 2.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to a sequence of *shift* and *xor* operations, see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) for an explanation, including an example calculation.